# SQL Server 2000, yes 2000 password hash

Tags: hash, sql-server-2000, passwords

I need to store a password has in a SQL server 2000 database. The information isn't critical but I really don't want to store the password in clear text. How can I get a unique hash (sha, sha1, md5, etc) in SQL server 2000 as HashBytes isn't available.

I'm not looking for compiled DLL or the ilk, I dont have access to the server, needs to be pure MS SQL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are undocumented (until later versions) functions in MS SQL Server 2000 called `pwdencrypt()` and `pwdcompare()`.

See this blog: [Undocumented SQL Server 2000 Functions](http://blogs.msdn.com/sathishcg/archive/2006/11/24/undocumented-sql-server-2000-functions.aspx)

Or on MSDN books online:

- [`PWDENCRYPT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822791.aspx)
- [`PWDCOMPARE()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx)

However, this function has been known to be insecure since at least 2002.  For some details see "[Cracking MS SQL Server passwords](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2002/07/08/cracking_ms_sql_server_passwords/)" at TheRegister.  I guess that's why it got replaced by Hashbytes.

If you can't upgrade your SQL Server instance or use any add-ons, this might be the best you can do.  Unless you hash the password in application code and store the resulting digest string, leaving the SQL Server out of the loop.